# The element type function<null> can't be assigned to list type 'widget'

Tags: flutter

I am a new flutter programmer and I am trying to build an online medicine application in which it has three tab sections:

- News
- Blogs
- Services

In the news part, I am trying to show an informative video through youtube channel, and, for that, I am taking reference of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feQhHStBVLE.

So I have used a `_buildvideo()` function inside a list-type widget in order to show informative video in news section but it is showing

> the element type function can't be assigned to list type 'widget'

I am stuck so badly in this part so how can I solve this problem?

My source code is

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final _ktabpages=<Widget>[
                         Container(
                          child:ListView(
                             children: <Widget>[
                               Container(
                                 width:430,
                                 height:175,
                                 child: Carousel(

                                   animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),//animation duration controlled with this line 
                                   boxFit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                   images: [
                                     AssetImage("assets/images/Medicines.jpg"),
                                     //AssetImage("assets/images/Doctors1.jpg"),
                                   ],
                                   autoplay: true,
                                   dotSize: 4.0,
                                   dotColor: Colors.grey,
                                   indicatorBgPadding: 4.0,
                                 ),
                                ),
                               Divider(thickness: 2,),

                               Container(width: 430,
                                height: 175,          
                                child: ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  children: <Widget>[//inside containers start here
                                   Container(color: Colors.cyan[100],width: 205,
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        //use list view with some text message to be displayed if pixel overflow occurs
                                        //add expanded or the widgets don't fill up space during screen rotation
                                      Expanded(child: Image.asset('assets/images/Medicines.jpg',)),
                                      ListTile(title: Text('E-pharm'),onTap: (){
                                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/secondRoute');
                                      },
                                      trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),onPressed: (){
                                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/secondRoute');
                                      },),)],
                                    ),
                                   ),VerticalDivider(),
                                   Container(color: Colors.cyan[100],width: 205,
                                    child: Column(//use list view with some text message to be displayed if pixel overflow occurs
                                      children: <Widget>[


                                        Expanded(child: Image.asset('assets/images/lab.png')),
                                        //try using divider
                                        ListTile(title: Text('Lab'),onTap: (){
                                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/labRoute');
                                        },
                                        trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),onPressed: (){
                                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/labRoute');
                                        },),)],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                 ],
                                ),
                              ),//current working conatiner
                               Divider(thickness: 2),
                    //conatiner with three iconButtons child care, mens care and womens care
                               Container( 
                                width: 430,
                                height: 100,
                                child: ListView(
                                  scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,

                                  children:
                                     <Widget>[
                                        Container(color: Colors.cyan[100],
                                       width: 146,
                                       child: Center(
                                         child: IconButton(iconSize: 100,icon: Image.asset('assets/images/BabyCare.jpg'),onPressed: (){
                                           Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/childCareRoute');
                                         },)),
                                        ),
                                        VerticalDivider(),
                                        Container(
                                         color: Colors.cyan[100],
                                          width: 146,
                                          // the following code distinguishes in the fact that image is used in the icon widget instead of the actual icon
                                          child: Center(child:IconButton(icon: Image.asset('assets/images/WomanCare.jpg'),onPressed: (){
                                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/womanCareView');
                                          },iconSize: 300,)
                                                   )           ),
                                        VerticalDivider(),                     
                                        Container(
                                         color: Colors.cyan[100],
                                          width: 146,
                                          // the following code distinguishes in the fact that image is used in the icon widget instead of the actual icon
                                          child: Center(child:IconButton(icon: Image.asset('assets/images/MenCare.jpg'),onPressed: (){
                                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/menCareView');
                                          },iconSize: 100,)
                                                   )           )          

                                  ],
                                )
                              ),
                               Divider(thickness: 2),
                                Container(
                                 width: 430,
                               height: 175,
                               color: Colors.cyan[100],
                               child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        //use list view with some text message to be displayed if pixel overflow occurs
                                        //add expanded or the widgets don't fill up space during screen rotation

                                        Expanded(child: Image.asset('assets/images/HealthCare.png',fit: BoxFit.cover,colorBlendMode: BlendMode.clear,),flex: 4,),
                                        ListTile(title: Text('Health Products'),onTap: (){
                                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/HealthProductView');
                                        },trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),onPressed: (){
                                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/HealthProductView');
                                        },),)],
                                    ),          
                               ),


                             ],
                           )),





                    //second tab containing the SajiloHealth blog section
                           //for blogsB
                           //Center(child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed:(){}),),
                           Container(),

                  //news section         
                            _buildVideo(Video video) {
             GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => VideoScreen(id: video.id),
    ),
  ),
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    height: 140.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black12,
          offset: Offset(0, 1),
          blurRadius: 6.0,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image(
          width: 150.0,
          image: NetworkImage(video.thumbnailUrl),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10.0),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            video.title,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
                    );

                 } 







@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _channel != null
          ? NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollDetails) {
                if (!_isLoading &&
                    _channel.videos.length != int.parse(_channel.videoCount) &&
                    scrollDetails.metrics.pixels ==
                        scrollDetails.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
                  _loadMoreVideos();
                }
                return false;
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1 + _channel.videos.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (index == 0) {
                    return null;
                                      }
                                      Video video = _channel.videos[index - 1];
                                      return _buildVideo(video);
                                                      },
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                : Center(
                                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                                        Theme.of(context).primaryColor, // Red
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                          );
                                        }



      ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate cannot understand your code but it seens that Some method in your code expects a widget to be returned. Normally, I would check all the build methods present.